# Me writing without consideration

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Next to the side, I'm out of position,
>   For a scientist put me in a bin,
>   But children appear when I jump,
>   A bad smell means success with me in.
>
> I may cause upset at the end,
>   I can be unfriendly, or even ill,
>   From the side is whence I shoot,
>   Believe me, I mean to kill.
>
> Gore follows me with rotting entrails,
>   Rest in peace, I paid a high price,
>   Show to me a pretentious sort,
>   I have authority on the ice.

**What am I?**
**Please explain each line in your answer.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something about this is a bit

> OFF.

```
Next to the side, I'm out of position,
For a scientist put me in a bin,
But children appear when I jump,
A bad smell means success with me in.
```

> In sport, if you are OFF-SIDE then you are out of position. A BOFFIN is a scientist. OFFSPRING are children. I think the bad smell would be B.O., yielding BOFFO.

```
I may cause upset at the end,
I can be unfriendly, or even ill,
From the side is whence I shoot,
Believe me, I mean to kill.
```

> If you OFFEND then you cause upset. Among the various nuances of "not quite right" that "off" can express are "ill-mannered" and "unwell". An OFFSHOOT comes off from the side of a plant. To OFF someone is to kill them.

```
Gore follows me with rotting entrails,
Rest in peace, I paid a high price,
Show to me a pretentious sort,
I have authority on the ice.
```

> OFFAL (think Al Gore) is entrails. If something is very expensive it might be a RIP-OFF. The pretentious person is a SHOW-OFF. If you are a person with authority -- a manager, executive, etc. -- then unlike many workers you probably have your own OFFICE.

Oh, and of course the title:

> OFFHAND.

Comment: Nicely done, the second line in the second verse is two definitions (mostly British informal). The third line is actually to do with plants although I can see why you didn't see that (it's not as solid as the other lines). Everything else is correct.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was looking for something more convoluted in v2l2. And, duh, I should have understood v2l3. Will edit.

Comment: The title could also be about *writing off* something, making it not worthy of consideration.

Comment: I suppose it could! I wonder whether hexomino intended both interpretations.